# matrix multiplication speed of odd dimensional matrices

Tags: c, performance, matrix

I am trying to understand the problem why matrix multiplication by row of square NxN sized matrices with `N=63, 127, 255, 511, 1023, 2047`
is quicker than those of `N=64, 128, 256, 512, 1024, 2048.`

This is my attempt so far:

I already ran perf instructions that gave me percentages of how many miss and hits I have and how many times do I need to visit main memory. 
In general, in the case of `N=2^k`, the multiplication is slower than when I have `N=2^k-1` so I have fewer GFLOPS. 
 I am thinking maybe it has something to do with the block size and the sets where everything is stored in cache, but I cant go much further.My code is implemented in c, if this has anything to do with this (I think it doesn't) and the cpu is `Intel Xeon Processor E5620`. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: How much faster?  actually, do you compare multiplication times for the same size, but with different storage alignment?  Otherwise it would come as no surprise that 63x63 be faster than 64x64.

Comment: I would look for cache collision issues

Comment: how much faster: for example, in the case of 63x63 matrix, I have 1,39, instead of 1,24 gflops in the case of 64x64 matrix. I compare multiplication times for the sizes I am giving above and the general case.

Comment: When saying cache collision issues, do you mean that the new data should go in the same sets and so the old ones would be replaced by the new in the cache? sorry if my english is kinda hard to understand.

Comment: Exactly. Powers of two sizes are involved in the representation of caches. If you have power-of-two displacements in the calculation, then bad things can happen. For instance, the code might work, in the heart of an inner loop, with several operands which map to the same cache line, and exceed the set size (or else overwhelm the replacement policy, which might not be full LRU).

Comment: I wonder whether valgrind's `cachegrind` tool could help analyze this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the distance between matrix rows is a power of 2, the likelihood of a cache collision while performing the inner product to compute the individual cell values is very high as you access the same column in all rows for each cross product.  The cache typically keeps 2, 4 or sometimes 8 different lines with the same low-order address bits.  On a 64x64 matrix, collisions are likely.  how likely depends on the cache size, cache architecture and actual algorithm used for matrix multiplication.

You should post the code, there might be good ideas around here to improve its efficiency.

You might improve performance by slicing the algorithm: computing the cross products using on a subset of the rows at a time and cumulating the results over all subsets.  Instead of 3 nested for loops, you would have 4 nested for loops with the same total number of multiplications but in a different order.